# Is There a Windows SMB Client Opened Implement

Tags: windows, filesystems, samba, smb, network-drive

There was a smbmrx sample code using RDBSS in WDK Vista.

But since WDK 7600 has been released, the sample was removed. -Do you know why?

I'm finding a nice sample code to learn RDBSS.

Is there a good open source better than smbmrx sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was probably removed because it was getting long in the tooth. It was never the full SMB redirector implementation shipped with Windows, it was some subset of the original version. It also uses TDI which is being deprecated in newer Windows in favor of WSK.

I don't know of any good open source examples. A network redirector is a complicated piece of software to write and there's value there for anyone brave enough to go for it. Why do you need this?

-scott

Comment: I made a network redirector based on smbmrx sample. But smbmrx was not implemented some important and difficult features. I want to also implement these features. There was a few documents for RDBSS, however. Without sample codes, it's too hard to understand how it works.

Comment: Sorry, I think you're mostly out of luck then. What are you trying to implement?

Comment: Change notification has been implemented. It wasn't smbmrx so that it was too difficult. I want to add fastio, caching and oplock mechanisms too. Before everything else I need to understand RDBSS.

Comment: Btw, are you Scott Noone of OSR?